# What Can I Do To Setup a Root Login In Debian 9?

Tags: debian, kde, login, root

I have been using Debian steadily since Sarge. In each version I have been able to login as root, with GUI, to do my administrative needs. I NEVER use root for day to day use.

I want to be able to have a root login in Debian 9 (stretch), with GUI. How can I alter the settings to get this setup?

Comment: It depends on your display manager.

Comment: Because my system started doing other quirky things I have opted to reload the system over again and I have opted to use  Cinnamon GUI instead, which still allows its user the choice.